# Why /etc/portage/package.use lines do not work installing Openshot?

Tags: emerge, funtoo, portage, openshot

On Funtoo Linux I has no sense how to solve requirements. I added lines but again and again I cannot run openshot installation

```
 # tail -n 5 /etc/portage/package.use
>=x11-libs/libXcursor-1.1.14 abi_x86_32

>=media-video/openshot-2.2.0 dbus opengl svg gui network printsupport widgets opengl webkit sql positioning webchannel python_targets_python3_4
>=dev-python/PyQt5-5.8.2 dbus opengl svg python_targets_python3_4


 # emerge openshot
Calculating dependencies... done!

!!! The ebuild selected to satisfy "dev-python/PyQt5[svg,webkit,python_targets_python3_4(-)?,python_targets_python3_5(-)?,-python_single_target_jython2_7(-),-python_single_target_pypy(-),-python_single_target_pypy3(-),-python_single_target_python2_7(-),-python_single_target_python3_6(-),python_single_target_python3_4(+)?,python_single_target_python3_5(+)?]" has unmet requirements.
- dev-python/PyQt5-5.8.2::python-kit USE="dbus opengl svg -bluetooth -debug -declarative -designer -doc -examples -gles2 -gui -help -location -multimedia -network -positioning -printsupport -sensors -serialport -sql -testlib -webchannel -webengine -webkit -websockets -widgets -x11extras -xmlpatterns" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 -python3_5 -python3_6"

  The following REQUIRED_USE flag constraints are unsatisfied:
    opengl? ( gui widgets ) svg? ( gui widgets ) webkit? ( gui network printsupport widgets )

  The above constraints are a subset of the following complete expression:
    any-of ( python_targets_python2_7 python_targets_python3_4 python_targets_python3_5 python_targets_python3_6 ) bluetooth? ( gui ) declarative? ( gui network ) designer? ( widgets ) help? ( gui widgets ) location? ( positioning ) multimedia? ( gui network ) opengl? ( gui widgets ) positioning? ( gui ) printsupport? ( gui widgets ) sensors? ( gui ) serialport? ( gui ) sql? ( widgets ) svg? ( gui widgets ) testlib? ( gui widgets ) webchannel? ( network ) webengine? ( network widgets? ( webchannel ) ) webkit? ( gui network printsupport widgets ) websockets? ( network ) widgets? ( gui ) xmlpatterns? ( network )

(dependency required by "media-video/openshot-2.2.0::media-kit" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "openshot" [argument])
```

Please. I've read manuals but I cannot understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit `/etc/portage/package.use`
and add `gui network printsupport widgets`:

```
dev-python/PyQt5 svg webkit gui network printsupport widgets
```